# replace, remove fragment and removing view doesn´t work in second run

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

My app selects one object of the listview and show the map. Works on first time running but in the second didn´t work. On third it works!

This is because of the inflate exception on the second time. It can´t return a view, or inflate it.

I need that every time it is selected something from the navigation drawer brings the map, im using replace and the method mentioned in many questions onDestroy, and obviusly removing the view when it is different from null.

Help would be appreciated!! Thanks!!

Code of the map:

```
public class mapfragmentplaces extends Fragment implements LocationListener {


protected LocationManager locationManager;
// GoogleMap googleMap;

LatLng myPosition;
private SupportMapFragment map;
private GoogleMap mMapView;


int fragVal2;
static Context ontext;
private static View view;


//lo que se ocupa para construir los sitios

String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

double mLatitude=0;
double mLongitude=0;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }



        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);



            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

            /*
            GoogleMapOptions gmo = (new GoogleMapOptions()).zoomControlsEnabled(false).rotateGesturesEnabled(false);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(gmo);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()     .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapFragmentHole, mapFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();   */

            map = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);


          /*  if (map == null) {
                map = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, map).commit();
            } */


            //  mMapView = fm.getMap();
            mMapView = map.getMap();
                // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            mMapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
             Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
             Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
       }

           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);



            mMapView.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Stores.class);
                   startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            // Clears all the existing markers 
            mMapView.clear();

            String Lugar = "Plaza fiesta";
            String  Desc = "Lugar bonito";

                Double Lat3 = 25.751188242782035;
                Double Lng3 = -100.3097140789032;

//                      notificacion(Results.toString());
                mMapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(new LatLng(Lat3,Lng3))
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker1))
                          .title(Lugar)
                          .snippet(Desc));


                List<HashMap<String, String>> list = setPlaceTag.getList();


                if (list!=null){
            //((Menu) map).clear();
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker. 
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);               

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mMapView.addMarker(markerOptions);            

            }
                }


        } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }
        return view;
        }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mMapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

    } 

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

     @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            if (fragment != null)
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        }

}
```

In my main activity Im calling the mapfragmentplaces with this:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
                //SelectItem(position);
        //  } //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "diste click a sitios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

            //Currently selected item in spinner first is airport!!!
            mTitle = setPlaceTag.getTag() ;             


            // Creating a fragment object
            mapfragmentplaces rFragment = new mapfragmentplaces();

            // Creating a Bundle object
            Bundle data = new Bundle();

            // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
            data.putString("position", setPlaceTag.getTag());

            // Setting the position to the fragment  it is the value of the spinner
            rFragment.setArguments(data);

            // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getSupportFragmentManager();

            // Creating a fragment transaction
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

            // Committing the transaction
            ft.commit();

            // Closing the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList); 


        }
    }
```

My xml for maps:

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your onCreateView method. I dont think its the correct way to inflate a xml file in oncreateview method. Please try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout.,container,false);
    //start inflating the view and return the view
     map = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    }
```

A good place to utilize and use view methods is onStart of the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    mMapView = map.getMap();
  }
```

Also I see that you are mixing the support package from the fragment. See this line:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

Make sure that all your import's and code for fragment are either from support package or from default package(api 11 or greater). This is a common source of bugs like classcastexception.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

It didn´t work.If I add just map = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); removing       android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
takes the same effect. Work on first time, second didnt and third did...

Could you post the full code in pastebin or something like that, I don´t understand well the order of the thins. How I will use mMapView? in onStart()? So All my code will go to onStart?

Comment: make mMapView a class level object. Declare it after the public MyClass extends fragment. As for the imports and support packages make sure you have used a consistent approach throughout your application. I once had to debug for 2 days to know that my imports were wrong. But not sure it is your case. I dont provide support via pastebin sorry for that. I will have a look at your question again.

Comment: @arnoldssss remove this line if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }

Comment: I remove that line, but think it could be usefull... I´ll add the class for charge the view as you say. 
I´m using in all my code this imports for fragments:
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

Think the issue is not in that side

Comment: the replace method which arguments should have?

ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

what is content_frame? Could be the error in that side?

Comment: I did the things you mentioned none of them work. It brings the same inflate exception on second run

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes you applied from here?