# ViewPager doesn´t show the other images, doesn´t swip

Tags: android, adapter

Is a simple viewpager for my application, head hurts. Help would be apreciated. It just bring the first image of default in the xml, doesnt brings the others and doesnt move for a second image when I swip it. I´m using small images , not the pixels that are mentioned in the xml... as you see I bring the ic_launcher, it does affect?.... need sleep. Easy reputation for you guys com on is the end phase for my app.

My ImageAdapter:

```
    package google.Bi;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
int[] GalImages;

ImageAdapter(Context context, int[] GalImages) {
    this.context = context;
    this.GalImages = GalImages;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    container.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}

@Override  
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {  
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((LinearLayout) view);  
}  
}
```

My activity that loads the adapter:

```
package google.Bi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class startactivivityAdapter extends Activity {
 //   Button b;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] { R.drawable.alta, R.drawable.baja,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.drawable.ic_action_good };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pageviewer);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, GalImages);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageChangeListener());
     //       b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    /*b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   int id=ListOfID[indexOfImage];
                   WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                            myWallpaperManager.setResource(id);
        }
    }); */
}

private int indexOfImage = 0;

private class MyPageChangeListener extends
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        indexOfImage = position;
    }
  }
}
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >





      <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layoutPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="450dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainImage"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="322dp"
            android:src="@drawable/main" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

```
container.addView(imageView, 0);
```

To

```
container.addView(imageView);
```

That 0 means indexed position within the container.  So you're actually saying always set the first child view to a new image.

`destroyItem()` needs to remove the view you made in `instantiateItem()`

In the xml you set the ViewPager's visiblity to `gone`.  Do you ever make it visible?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, dud I did what you say but the app doesnt swip the image :C just brings the default image. I´ll edit dthe question with the changes

Comment: you are the best!! many thanks... dont you want more stupid questions like this? hahah just give me your email ... and I´ll sent you questions like this... I can give you more reputation... maybe are two questions more... one is the validation of the internet and gps before the app starts... and the other one is a question I´ve made in this link:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462142/viewpager-doesn%C2%B4t-show-the-other-images-doesn%C2%B4t-swip/24462816#24462816 or in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392283/replace-remove-fragment-and-removing-view-doesn%C2%B4t-work-in-second-run/24392481?noredirect=1#comment37729112_24392481   if you help me that 4/5 questions could be yours, think you have many experience on android field

Comment: btw is the same project for all those questions , I can send you the whole code.